# Club different MQTT Topic data into one JSON string in node red

Tags: javascript, mqtt, node-red

How can I club all the MQTT Topic data in one JSON String
I was able to get JSON string for the individual topic only like this

```
 "{"time":1549737900821,"payload":"1997.32","topic":"RotateZ"}"
  {"time":1549737900821,"payload":"1954.32","topic":"RotateY"}"
```

but I want to display all the topic data in one JSON string only for example

`"{"time":1549737900821,
    "RotateZ":"1997.32",
    "RotateY":"1954.32"}"`

I am using mentioned below code in function node

```
var topic = msg.topic;
var d = new Date();
var t = d.getTime();
payload = {"time":t, "payload" : msg.payload ,"topic": topic }
msg.payload = payload;
return msg;
```

what modification will help me to make it work?
Any suggestion on this will be a great help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Join` node. Set Manual, Combine each msg.payload to create `a key/value object` using the value of `msg.topic` as the key. On output add timestamp in simle function like this :

```
var d = new Date();
msg.payload.time = d.getTime();
return msg;
```